# ReactJS | Concat Arrays Inside Of Object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, concatenation

im currently working on a React JS App and i have an **Array** which has **Objects** in it, and inside the **Objects** it has **Arrays**.

Here's the code first,

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      namaSantri: null,
      examTitle: 'PLP BAHAS Arab Talaqqi',
      examLevel: 0,
      examType: 'Ujian 1 Tulis',
      vocabQ: [{questionTitle: 'Question Title', question: ['Question 1', 'Question 2']}],

    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var questionEx = {questionTitle: 'Question Title2', question: ['Question 1']}
    var anotherArray = ['Question 2']
    var addIndex = questionEx.question.concat(anotherArray)

    this.setState({
      vocabQ: [...this.state.vocabQ, addIndex]
    })
  }
```

So i have an Array whis is vocabQ here, and it contains Objects which contains my QuestionTitles and my Questions Array.

I want to create an input program for the Quesiton Object ( that contains questionTitle and questions ) here, so i tried to concat my array at addIndex but it show nothing. Help?

My render,

```
render() {
    /**SOMETHING THAT YOU NEED TO WRITE TO OUTPUT AN ARRAY? */
    const map = this.state.vocabQ.map((d) => <p key={d.questionTitle}>{d.questionTitle}&nbsp;{d.question}</p>);

    return (
      <div /**DIV PAGE START */
        className="App">

        <div /**DIV HEADER START */
          className="DivHeader">

          <Center>
            <p className="ExamTitle">{this.state.examTitle}</p>
          </Center>

          <Center>
          <p className="ExamLevel">Level&nbsp;{this.state.examLevel}</p>
          </Center>

          <Center>
          <p className="ExamType">{this.state.examType}</p>
          </Center>

          <Center>
            <div className="NameInput">
              <InputText value={this.state.namaSantri} onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.namaSantri})} />
              {/**HERE IS WHERE THE ARRAY SHOULD BE */}
              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{map}</span>
            </div>
          </Center>

        {/**DIV HEADER END */}
        </div>

        <div /**DIV VOCAB QUESTIONS START */> 

        {/**DIV VOCAB QUESTIONS END */}
        </div>

      {/**DIV PAGE END*/}
      </div >
    );
  }
```

**NB: It only show "Question Title Question 1Question 2"**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGVho.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var questionEx = {questionTitle: 'Question Title2', question: ['Question 1']}
    var anotherArray = ['Question 2']
    var addIndex = questionEx.question.concat(anotherArray)

    this.setState({
      vocabQ: [...this.state.vocabQ, ...addIndex]  //<----This "..." is the part that has changed
    })
  }
```

You basically have to use the spread operator on both arrays in order for it to work the way you want to. Head to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operatorhttps://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator to learn a bit more about that.

Comment: Im sorry but it doesn't work, thanks for the comment tho